# Error: 'MonetDBLite' is not an exported object from 'namespace:MonetDBLite'

Tags: r, survey, monetdblite

Working through a download script for CPS data [found here](https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/master/Current%20Population%20Survey/download%20all%20microdata.R). Using the script verbatim, per recent update, except for the Java modification that I added for my environment (below) to fix a previous error in `loadnamespace`. While I am familiar with the basics of R, this is my first foray into `MonetDBLite`.

```
# configure Java
if (Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="")
  Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")
library(rJava)
```

Now I am getting the following error, which generally comes after 380,000 of the 400,000 cps asec lines are processed.

```
Warning message:
In readLines(url) :
  incomplete final line found on 'http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/march/asec2015early_pubuse.dd.txt'
Error in dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbfolder) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': Error: 'MonetDBLite' is not an exported object from 'namespace:MonetDBLite'
```

Comment: if hannes' suggestion does not solve the problem, please open an issue at https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree thanks

Comment: @AnthonyDamico opened ticket: https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/issues/123

Answer (score 1):

MonetDBLite has just been updated on CRAN, please reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I un-installed and re-installed. Still stalls at lines 380k.